# Tango Unity examples crashing when built with Unity 2017.1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I just installed Unity 2017.1.0f3 and tried to compile the examples but all of them crash at start on my Lenovo Phab 2 Pro (Tango version 1.55).

I loaded the project tango-examples-unity\UnityExamples in Unity without modifying it and Unity converts it to the Unity 2017.1.0f3 version. The building seems to run fine but on the phone the resulting app crashes at start.

Everything worked fine for me on Unity 5.6. Maybe the Tango SDK is simply not supported yet by Unity 2017.1 but I could not find any information on that.

Here are the console output on Unity after building the app and the logs of the Tango when I launch the app and it crashes.

[Unity console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzj5V.png)

Tango Logs :

```
    07-13 18:26:07.867 1261-1409/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } from com.android.launcher3 (pid=4828, uid=10025) requires com.google.android.launcher.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to receiver com.google.android.gms/.icing.proxy.ApplicationLauncherReceiver
    07-13 18:26:07.868 1261-1409/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$GmsExternalReceiver requires com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to sender com.android.launcher3 (uid 10025)
    07-13 18:26:07.882 544-3682/? E/audio_route: audio_route_apply_and_update_path:name(speaker-protected)
    07-13 18:26:07.882 544-3682/? E/audio_route: audio_route_apply_and_update_path:name(vi-feedback)
    07-13 18:26:07.882 544-3682/? E/voice: voice_is_in_call_rec_stream: input stream is NULL
    07-13 18:26:07.883 544-3682/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
    07-13 18:26:07.883 544-3682/? E/audio_route: audio_route_apply_and_update_path:name(spkr-vi-record)
    07-13 18:26:07.894 544-3682/? E/voice: voice_is_in_call_rec_stream: input stream is NULL
    07-13 18:26:07.894 544-3682/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE Returned = -19
    07-13 18:26:07.894 544-3682/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB audproc returned = -19
    07-13 18:26:07.894 544-3682/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
    07-13 18:26:07.894 544-3682/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
    07-13 18:26:07.895 544-3682/? E/audio_route: audio_route_apply_and_update_path:name(low-latency-playback speaker-protected)
    07-13 18:26:07.936 8061-8061/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                     Process: com.projecttango.unityexamples, PID: 8061
                                                     java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
                                                     Unity version     : 2017.1.0f3
                                                     Device model      : LENOVO Lenovo PB2-690M
                                                     Device fingerprint: Lenovo/phinny_row/PB2PRO:6.0.1/MMB29M/PB2-690M_S200100_170228:user/release-keys

                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;)V in class Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer' appears in /data/app/com.projecttango.unityexamples-2/base.apk)
                                                         at com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity.onCreate(GoogleUnityActivity.java:106)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5418)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    07-13 18:26:07.938 1261-4787/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.projecttango.unityexamples/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity
    07-13 18:26:08.290 1261-1453/? E/WallpaperManagerService: onEvent:settings_system.xml.bak,changedFile:/data/system/users/0/settings_system.xml.bak
    07-13 18:26:08.294 1261-1453/? E/WallpaperManagerService: onEvent:settings_system.xml,changedFile:/data/system/users/0/settings_system.xml
    07-13 18:26:08.294 1261-1453/? E/WallpaperManagerService: onEvent:settings_system.xml.bak,changedFile:/data/system/users/0/settings_system.xml.bak
    07-13 18:26:08.545 1261-1409/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{e8388eb u0 com.projecttango.unityexamples/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity t822 f}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing it has been confirmed that Unity 2017.1 is currently not supported by the Tango SDK, we only support Unity 5.6 at this time.